# Insert space at specified position in a file

Tags: shell, command-line, sed, awk

I have this sample file:

```
234234|111||J1X0H8|SERP||R|D|666|M
234235|222||J1X0N5|SERP||C||555|M
```

For each line, I need to insert a space after the 3rd character of the 4th column, like so:

```
234234|111||J1X 0H8|SERP||R|D|666|M
234235|222||J1X 0N5|SERP||C||555|M
```

I've been trying to use the sed and awks commands, but with no positive results. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

With awk, it's

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{sub(/^.../, "& ", $4); print}' file
```

But that cannot edit in-place, so you have to:

```
t=$(mktemp)
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{sub(/^.../, "& ", $4); print}' file > "$t" && mv "$t" file
```

With sed,

```
sed -i 's/^[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|.../& /' file
```

If you want to validate the postal code, then

```
sed -i 's/^\([^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]\)\([[:digit:]][[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]|\)/\1 \2/' file
```